# How to make a rethinkdb atomic update if document exists, insert otherwise?

Tags: rethinkdb

How to make a rethinkdb atomic update if document exists, insert otherwise?

I want to do something like:

```js
var tab = r.db('agflow').table('test');
r.expr([{id: 1, n: 0, x: 11}, {id: 2, n: 0, x: 12}]).forEach(function(row){
  var _id = row('id');
  return r.branch(
    tab.get(_id).eq(null),  // 1
    tab.insert(row),        // 2 
    tab.get(_id).update(function(row2){return {n: row2('n').add(row('n'))}}) // 3
  )})
```

However this is not fully atomic, because between the time when we check if document exists (1) and inserting it (2) some other thread may insert it.

How to make this query atomic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the inner part atomic, you can use `replace`:

```
tab.get(_id).replace(function(row2){
  return r.expr({id: _id, n: row2('n').add(row('n'))})
          .default(row)
})
```

Using `replace` is the only way at the moment to perform fully atomic upserts with non-trivial update operations.

Comment: How can i update a field or insert a document? Is it possible to actually update a field atomically like a counter, quantity field or last_visit timestamp? I don't want to create a new document with updated data, I want to update a counter field. for user A that has counter x=1 I want counter to be x++ (x=2) I found the inc instruction but no way to do a proper atomic upsert, similar to what zincrby in Redis does

Answer (score 20):

I think the solution is passing

```
conflict="update"
```

to the insert method.

Als see [RethinkDB documentation on insert](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/insert/)

Comment: Update: In this particular case you might want to implement a [conflict resolution function](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/insert/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard database operation called an "upsert".

> #### Does RethinkDB support upserts?
>
> Another question from Sergio
>   Tulentsev. The first public release didn't include support for
>   upserts, but now it can be done by passing an extra flag to insert:
>
> ```
> r.table('marvel').insert({ 
>       superhero: 'Iron Man', 
>       superpower: 'Arc Reactor' 
>   }, {upsert: true}).run()
> ```
>
> When set to true, the new document
>   from insert will overwrite the existing one.
>
> <sub>cite: [Answers to common questions about RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/answers-to-common-questions/)</sub>

Comment: I know upsert. The case is that I don't want to overwrite. I want to update existing document.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't implement a traditional [upsert](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert).

Comment: I got an error using upsert with node.js client 2.3.2 - ReqlServerCompileError: Unrecognized optional argument `upsert` in:
r.db("myDB").table("mytable").insert({"userId":  something, "lastUpdate": timestamp }, {"upsert": true})

Comment: `Unrecognized optional argument upsert.`

Comment: This might have changed since.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out how to do it.

The solution is to firstly try `insert`, and if it fail we make `update`:

```js
var tab = r.db('agflow').table('test');
tab.delete();
r.expr([{id: 1, n: 0, x: 11}, {id: 2, n: 0, x: 12}]).forEach(function(row){
  var _id = row('id');
  var res = tab.insert(row);
  return r.branch(
    res('inserted').eq(1),
    res,
    tab.get(_id).update(function(row2){return {n: row2('n').add(1)}})
  )})
```

Comment: are you sure this will be performed atomically?

Comment: so you can use this for instance to increment/update a field or insert a document in case the secondary index does not exist? Similar to what you can do with http://redis.io/commands/zincrby ? Lets say i have a username and a score for that user, every time the user clicks a button his score increases by +1, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This is not atomic. Instead you need to pass a conflict resolution argument the insert method.